# How to implement TLS 1.2 in an Android Xamarin C# receive an email, outlook.office365 using POP

Tags: authentication, email, xamarin.android, pop3

Until late last week, emails sent to the android phone were being receiving and displayed fine. I've been told that 'it looks as though Microsoft have now fully discontinued the use of the smtp authentication, without TLS 1.2.'

How can I implement TLS 1.2 in the code? Code is below - it worked fine till last Friday. The app fails at the line ' client.Authenticate' with the error message 'Authentication failed'. The username and password are correct (but changed here for obvious reasons).

```
        public void CheckForEmailsFromSupportPOP2(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        int numCountEmailsDownloaded = 0;
        string strAllIncidentNumbers = "";

        try
        {

            //int numCount = 1;

            string pathLog = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            string fileNameLog = Path.Combine(pathLog, "pop3.txt");

            using (var client = new Pop3Client(new ProtocolLogger(fileNameLog)))
            {
                client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

                client.Authenticate("mobile1@zxcv.co.uk", "password");  //<<<<<<<<<FAILS HERE

                for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                {

                    var message = client.GetMessage(i);
```

... and so on.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have clients that can’t use TLS1.2, you may use the opt-in legacy endpoint by now. However, in 2022, Microsoft official team plan to disable those older TLS versions to secure their customers and meet compliance requirements. Due to significant usage, Microsoft official team has created an opt-in endpoint that legacy clients can use with TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. However, only WW customers will be able to use this new endpoint. To take advantage of this new endpoint, you will have to:

1. Set the AllowLegacyTLSClients parameter on the Set-TransportConfig cmdlet to True.
2. Legacy clients and devices will need to be configured to submit using the new endpoint smtp-legacy.office365.com.

If you want to use TLS1.2 early, you can set the AllowLegacyTLSClients parameter to False. In fact, since September 2021, Microsoft has rejected a small percentage of connections that use TLS1.0 for SMTP AUTH. For more details about this, you may refer to these links: "https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/new-opt-in-endpoint-available-for-smtp-auth-clients-still/ba-p/2659652" and "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/opt-in-exchange-online-endpoint-for-legacy-tls-using-smtp-auth".